# What is wrong with this Jquery Ajax request in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am using the following code to make a request to a PHP script:

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "myAPI.php",
            data: {
                   orderById: 2,
                   action: 'returnStuff',
                   },
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                    var $targetToMove = $('.shape.'+value.attr_name);
                    //if element already exists on page, move it to the end of the container
                    if($('.'+value.xml_name).length){
                            $('.container').append($targetToMove);
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Here is a simplified example of my return data

```
{"data":{"0":{"id":"1","name":"This","color":"blue"},
         "1":{"id":"2","name":"That","color":"red"},
         "2":{"id":"3","name":"whatever","color":"blue"}}}
```

If the orderById equals 1, the data is returned numerically from lowest to highest by the id. If it equals 2 it is returned numerically from highest to lowest like this:

```
{"data":{"0":{"id":"3","name":"whatever","color":"blue"},
         "1":{"id":"2","name":"That","color":"red"},
         "2":{"id":"1","name":"This","color":"blue"}}}
```

The idea is that the API returns the data in the order I want, then on success in the ajax call, the elements are re-arranged on the page in the order of the returned data object.

This works how I intend in Firefox, but in Chrome, whenever I console log the data on success, the order is always the same, despite the console indicating the response from my API is in the correct order.

What am I missing? I can't tell if this is a caching issue or if I am just overlooking something in my javascript.

Answer (score 5):

`Object` properties order is not guaranteed in JavaScript. You would rather use `Array` for that

Answer (score 1):

Format you json to look like this:

```
{"data":[{"id":"3","name":"whatever","color":"blue"},{"id":"2","name":"That","color":"red"},{"id":"1","name":"This","color":"blue"}]}
```

Comment: Is this an option I can choose in PHP's json_encode, or should I just manually create the json?

Comment: your json encode should look like this: `json_encode(array("data"=>$array))` where $array is the array of items in the wanted order

Comment: My json is now formatted as indicated, but order still does not appear to matter. when I do typeof(data.data[0]) JS still says an object, and Chrome is still not respecting the order the json is returned. Must still be missing something.

Comment: Ultimate solution was to greatly simplify my php return to just a simple JS array holding the class values in the order I wanted them to appear. The large associative array(object) php was returning would have required more work than necessary.

Comment: data.data is now a array of objects that is ordered in the order of that comes from the php file